# how to avoid attribute error from classes?

Tags: python, selenium, class, selenium-webdriver

I made a class as the basic setup of the `selenium driver`. and I added methods to it. I want to access method of the class from a context manager I tried to create an object of the class in the `context manager` and access the method but I failed. how do I do it?

I even do not have any idea whats wrong in this code. please help me.

```
class SeleniumDriver:
     '''basic setup for chromedriver(selenium)'''

     def __init__(self, 
             driversource='C:\\Users\Ewis\Downloads\chromedriver.exe',
             url = ('https://realpython.com/')
             ):
        self.driversource = driversource
        self.url = url # this tuple

    def __enter__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=self.driversource)
        for urls in self.url:
            self.driver.get(urls)
        return self.driver, Keys

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_trace):
        self.driver.quit()

# and this code(another project)

from seleniumdriver import SeleniumDriver

with SeleniumDriver() as packed:

    seldriver1 = SeleniumDriver()
    driver = packed[0]
    urls = ('https://realpython.com/','https://stackoverflow.com/')
    resp = seldriver1.geturl(urls)
    for url in resp:
        title, url = resp.titleurl()
        print(title, '\n', url,'\n')
```

**Error :**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\python\progs\web\selenium\navigation_commands\navigation_commands.py", line 9, in 
>           for url in resp:
>         File "c:\python\progs\my_modules\seleniumdriver\seleniumdriver.py", line 22, in geturl
>           yield (self.driver).get(url)
>       AttributeError: 'SeleniumDriver' object has no attribute 'driver'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is enough to resolve all problems but:

You have to use `packed[0]` which is created using `with` and it executes `__enter__` which creates `self.driver`

```
resp = packed[0].geturl(urls)
```

But you use `seldriver1` which is created using `seldriver1 = SeleniumDriver()` which doesn't execute `__enter__` so it doesn't create `self.driver` (`seldriver1.driver`) and you get error:

```
'SeleniumDriver' object has no attribute 'driver'
```

---

```
from seleniumdriver import SeleniumDriver

with SeleniumDriver() as packed:

    urls = ('https://realpython.com/','https://stackoverflow.com/')
    resp = packed[0].geturl(urls)

    for url in resp:
        title, url = resp.titleurl()
        print(title, '\n', url,'\n')
```

---

Your code seems weird for me and it may need much more changes to work correctly.

---

**EDIT:** this code works for me.

Because I use Firefox on Linux and I don't have to set `driversource` so I added `None` to run without `driversource`

I removed `get(url)` from `__enter__` because it is useless. You can't get two pages in `__enter__` and use them later in `for` loop because `Selenium` doesn't keep information about first page when you open second page.

```
from selenium import webdriver


class SeleniumDriver:
    '''basic setup for chromedriver(selenium)'''
    def __init__(self, driversource='C:\\Users\Ewis\Downloads\chromedriver.exe'):
        self.driversource = driversource

    def __enter__(self):
        if self.driversource:
            #self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=self.driversource)
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=self.driversource)
        else:
            #self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        return self.driver

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_trace):
        self.driver.quit()


with SeleniumDriver(None) as driver:
    urls = ('https://realpython.com/', 'https://stackoverflow.com/')
    for url in urls:
        driver.get(url)
        title = driver.title
        print(title, '\n', url,'\n')
```